# tasks.loop timer is repeatedly executing in discord.py

Tags: discord, atom-editor, discord.py

So I'm making a bot that'll post the [Wednesday Frog](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/091/264/665.jpg) meme every Wednesday. To do this, I'm using discord.py's tasks.loop function which in theory should run once every 24 hours in the finished version. Thing is though no matter how many hours, minutes or seconds I set it to, It spams my chat with either the meme or "It's not Wednesday," almost every second.

The code:

```
import discord
import datetime
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ')')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    wednesdayCheck.start()
    print("Lets see if it's wednesday.")

@tasks.loop(hours=2)
async def wednesdayCheck():
    if datetime.datetime.today().weekday() == 2:
        for guild in client.guilds:
            for channel in guild.text_channels:
                await channel.send(file=discord.File('Meme.jpg'))
    elif datetime.datetime.today().weekday() != 2:
        for guild in client.guilds:
            for channel in guild.text_channels:
                await channel.send("It's not Wednesday")
```

Any help with making the function follow the timer as intended will be much apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try  putting the `.start()` outside of the `on_ready()` function, just above the `bot.run()`.
There is no guarantee that the `on_ready()` function only runs once.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_ready#discord.on_ready

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution to your problem:

Create a global boolean variable that ensures the block is only run once in on_ready

```
ON_READY_FIRST_RUN = True

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global ON_READY_FIRST_RUN
    if ON_READY_FIRST_RUN:
        wednesdayCheck.start()
        print("Lets see if it's Wednesday.")
        ON_READY_FIRST_RUN = False
```

I have been trying to set up a bot to send a message every weekday morning but for some reason can't get the @tasks.loop to execute. Hope this helps you though!

Edit: I was trying to use @tasks.before_loop but I just threw that code in my @tasks.loop and now this works perfectly!